# docker image push to ecr repo using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, aws-cli

installed aws cli (using windows)
created iam user
set up both keys from iam user
created ecr repo
in view push commands option,
when copied the first command, and entered in cli, it shows:

.Password was unexpected at this time.

command I entered by copying is:
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 899190035275.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

by this very command , it should log in in my shell (using vscode)
it is not able to log in

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the ECR login credentials:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION --profile $AWS_PROFILE
```

You may or may not need to specify the region and profile depending on your setup.

The output can be piped into the `docker login --password-stdin` command or you can copy it and then paste into an interactive `docker login`.

There's a blog post (aimed at Linux but might still be useful) [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2022/02/pushing-docker-images-from-gitlab-to-aws-ecr/).